# Why cannot find the response part in swagger api request? 404 error / this is the jsp project

Tags: java, api, rest, jsp, swagger

I built a dummy api and I want to test it on swagger. The swagger.json has been successfully generated and executed to show the swagger UI.
But there is the 404 error that cannot find the response part.
How can I solve this?

This is the built swagger UI.
[image]

And this is the code.

```
@Service
@Api
public class className () {


@GET
@Path("/oauth2/authorize")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@ApiOperation(value = "Authorization Grant", notes = "Authorization Grant")
@ApiResponses(value = {
    @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Successfully Granted the Authorization"), 
    @ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "Missing or invalid request body"), 
    @ApiResponse(code = 403, message = "Forbidden"),  
    @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "Schema not found"),        
    @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Internal error")})
public Response authorizationGrant(
        @HeaderParam("X-AUTH-TOKEN") final String token,
        @HeaderParam("X-CSRF-TOKEN") final String csrftoken,
        @ApiParam(value = "Client ID", required = true) @QueryParam("Client ID") final String clientId, 
        @ApiParam(value = "Scope", required = true) @QueryParam("Scope") final String scope, 
        @ApiParam(value = "Redirect Uri", required = true) @QueryParam("Redirect Uri") final String redirectUri, 
        @ApiParam(value = "Response Type", required = true) @QueryParam("Response Type") final String responseType ) throws AccessDeniedException {
   return Response
            .status(Response.Status.OK)
            .entity("{\"hello\": \"This is a JSON response\"}")
            .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .build();
}
```

}

Please tell me what you need more to be clear with this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem solved!!!

I hope this answer could help for others who are suffered from this trouble. :)

The error was from the @Api Definition part. I should have define the path in that part.
This is the corrected code.

```
@Path("/oauth2")
@Service
@Api
public class className () {
    .....
    @GET
    @Path("/authorize")
    .....
```

}

As you can see the @Api definition part requires the @Path annotation.
:)